# CSS: strong padding on all sides

Tags: html, css

I have simple HTML and CSS code and I have little issue.

I have span where is some text and STRONG. And now when I use padding or margin on STRONG on all sides padding is used only on RIGHT AND LEFT but I need use PADDING or MARGIN on all sides.

Is there any option how can I solve thuis problem?

```css
div {
  background: red;
  padding: 30px;
}

strong {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    IJDDN<br>
    <strong>!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</strong><br>
    ajoSa saS ajsno<br>
    JSHaojns auS aksuoaS ausbn aSOUIAJ<br>
    ajshaoSNINas auBNSa
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to modify the structure?

Comment: Just add display: inline-block to the style of the strong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be the solution for your problem, just add `display: inline-block;` to the style of the `<strong>`

```css
div {
  background: red;
  padding: 30px;
}

strong {
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    IJDDN<br>
    <strong>!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</strong><br>
    ajoSa saS ajsno<br>
    JSHaojns auS aksuoaS ausbn aSOUIAJ<br>
    ajshaoSNINas auBNSa
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool. Better answer as block just takes more space.